# C++ programming more efficient way to do

Tags: c++, computer-science

This program is running but I am looking for a more efficient way to run this program. 
You can see I commented out the code because I think it can work out without that extra code. however, I am a little bit confused. 
in the else statement, I am trying to decrement the x value so it becomes x=8 and runs the loop again and decrement again.
But it is not working. 
can anyone help me what should I do? thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y;

    if (x = 9) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow (x, 2) + 4* pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
            else {
                x--;

            }
    }
    /*   if (x = 8) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 7) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 6) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 5) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 4) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 3) {
         for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
             if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                 cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 2) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout << "x value is : " << x << endl << "y value is: " << y<<endl;
    }
     if (x = 1) {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            if (3 * pow(x, 2) + 4 * pow(y, 2) == 271)
                cout <<"x value is : "<< x <<endl<<"y value is: "<< y<<endl;
    }

    */

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `if (x = 9)` does? If you understand what it does, why are you using `if` at all? Also, it sounds like your goal is to find all combinations of `x` and `y` where both are integers from 0 to 8, inclusive, that solve the equation given. You can do this with simple algebra.

Comment: All those cases seem to be identical. Looks like a good place to use a function. Also look at the compiler warnings. It the compiler isn't telling you `if (x = 9)` is probably wrong, you need to turn up the warning level.

Comment: A bunch of `if (x == #)` statements should probably be replaced with `switch(x)`

Comment: Why have you posted so much commented-out code?

Comment: Just use a for loop for the x value.

Comment: `if (x = 9) ...` is not the same as `if (x == 9) ...` in C++ - or Java or most other modern computer languages, for that matter.  When you've figured that out you'll have made a good start ...

Comment: **Read a good C++ programming book**. Compile with all warnings and debug info : `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Use the debugger `gdb`

Comment: Don't use `pow(x,2)` but `x*x`

Comment: A elementary examination of the equation used in code shows it will produce no output, other than the `system"PAUSE")`, EVEN if all the commented code is un-commented.  Writing a program that produces no output is trivial.

Comment: I assume you meant if(x==9) and not if(x=9).  But what I don't think you realize is that you never set the x variable before that.  It will just be random garbage in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a for loop to iterate over values of `x`:

```
for (x = 9; x > 0; x--) {
    for (y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        if (3 * pow (x, 2) + 4* pow(y, 2) == 271) {
            cout << "x: " << x << endl << "y: " << y << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `pow(x,2)` -it is a `double`- but just `x*x` etc

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I agree with your suggestion, but I didn't change the author's implementation (accept the long prints) on purpose.